# Total Product Life Cycle API?

Tags: openfda

I am unable to find any endpoint(s) to fetch TPLC related details in the OpenFDA website or may be i've overlooked.

Is there is an API or other ways to retrieve TPLC related details, could you pls share ? Thanks In Advance. Also, Here is the TPLC website
URL: https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfTPLC/tplc.cfm

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, openFDA does not yet have this dataset available via API.

Comment: Hi @Denis can you elaborate on this? How do you know this, where can others find this information, etc. Please and thanks!